# Kubernetes xray-daemon pod give error Back-off restarting failed container

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a container that has some pods , one of them failed called `xray-daemon-x9m8l` failed
with error `Back-off restarting failed container` any hint why this happens

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the pod logs for details.

```
kubectl logs xray-daemon-x9m8l -p
```

Should give some ideas if the crash was caused due to application failure. It could be due to many reasons

-p option gives you the logs of a previously crashed pod.

```
kubectl describe po xray-daemon-x9m8l
```

May also give you some ideas

Comment: logs empty , describe pod gove me Warning  BackOff  3m36s (x5081 over 18h)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container , I wonder if that error make my container not working